# Reverse copy of an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, object

my code isn't working.

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] array) {

    int[] result = new int[10];
    int j = array.length;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        result[i] = array[j];
        j++;
     }

    return result;
}
```

The method should return a reverse copy of an integer array.

Comment: Arrays start at index 0. Also, you're incrementing `j` instead of decrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `j` should be set to `array.length - 1`.
Second, `i` should start at 0.
Third, Rather than incrementing the `j` value there, you should decrement the `j` value.

Comment: Thanks a lot!This was very helpful!